# Couldn't get pcap handle, exiting

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, network-interface, error-handling

I got an error when i use wash tool to display the networks around me that has wps enabled.

But i had an unexpected error while i'm trying to run that.

```
root@Shadow:~# wash --interface wlan0
[X] ERROR: pcap_activate status -1
[X] PCAP: generic error code
couldn't get pcap handle, exiting
```

I use TP-Link TL-WN722N on Monitor mode.

Comment: Cant add an answer, but this works on Kali:

`apt-get purge --auto-remove reaver`

`apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev`

then follow steps of instaling reaver from https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x .

Credits to https://zsecurity.org/

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you for this.

Comment: @ToTenMilan it should be a correct answer! Thanks man!